# Consolidating csv file with python. 1 ID, multiple entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need to be able to run through a csv with repeating id's and output the id's with the non-repeating values on one line per id. Have been trying to use pandas for reading the csv.

What I have:

```
Id, Bin  
1, a1  
1, a2  
1, b2  
2, a4  
2, a5  
2, b4  
2, b5
```

What I want:

```
Id, Bin  
1, a1, a2, b2  
2, a4, a5, b4, b5
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your input file is called `id_input.csv`.

So, in my solution i'll use `groupby` from `itertools` module like this example:

id_input.csv:

```
Id, Bin  
1, a1  
1, a2  
1, b2  
2, a4  
2, a5  
2, b4  
2, b5
```

The script, which will print your desired output is:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = list(k.replace("\n", "").strip().split(",") for k in open("id_input.csv", 'r'))


for key, val in groupby(data, lambda x : x[0]):
    if key != "Id":
        print("%s, %s" %(key, ",".join(k[1] for k in list(val))))
```

Output:

```
1,  a1, a2, b2
2,  a4, a5, b4, b5
```